# What can a router do to interfere with Apple Music?

Tags: itunes, network, apple-music

I have two routers, both connected to the same internet connection:

1. One that is shared with all my roommates and does not support 802.11ac, let's call it "slow".
2. One that I own and manage (TP-Link Archer C58), does support 802.11ac and to which both my Apple TV is connected, let's call it "fast".

Recently I kept having problems with Apple Music: songs are skipped, songs cannot be downloaded. I either get a -3150 error and “Can't activate a connection to the network” or it keeps spinning with no results.

After numerous attempts at troubleshooting, I switched back to the "slow" router: it works immediately. So I presume there's something wrong with the configuration of the "fast" router: what could it be? Everything else works perfectly.

Thanks!

Comment: How are they 'shared' by the same internet connection? That is, how are they physically connected? Are they connected to another router upstream?

Comment: Is that router blocking the Apple Music site, or streaming music sites in general?  After connecting the "fast" router, did you release and refresh your DHCP config as well as flush your DNS cache?

Comment: @IconDaemon they are connected to the same router (placed in the house we share a wall with), with two different cables

Comment: @Allan it does not block Apple Music site, I can browse Apple Music from iTunes without problems, it just doesn't play/download music. I'm flushing my DNS cache, what else should I do?

Comment: Nothing more from the Apple side...the issue is at the router.   Other than resetting the router to factory default and not using any security (WPA or WEP) just for diagnostics, it's time to engage the support group from TP-Link.